# Datetime format in QGIS Points to Paths plugin

Tags: qgis, datetime

At 2.18.6, I am trying to use the PointstoPaths plugin.

My input layer has a datetime string field with the following format:

2015-01-25 13:45:50  [Please note the blank between date and time.]

However, the PointstoPaths window displays a date format *example* of:

%Y%m%dT%H:%M:%S    [Here, please note the 'T' between date and time]

Here's a screenshot:

[image]

If I use PointstoPaths with the following datetime format (which matches my data):

%Y%m%d %H:%M:%S  [with a blank!]

This error is returned:

[image]

If I subsequently edit my datetime string field to change the blank to a 'T', the tool executes perfectly.  Thus I am led to believe that the 'T' is required.  But I don't know what the 'T' represents.  A review of the [Python datetime web pag](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html)e turned up nothing.

Sorry if this is long winded, but I don't understand the 'T'!

Answer (score 3):

Actually, you are almost there. In your tested case, the hyphen (short dash) between %Y, %m, %d were missing.

`PointsToPath` accepts both formats as below (as far as such field is string).

- If the string is `'2015-01-25 13:45:50'`, the format is `%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S`
- If the string is `'2015-01-25T13:45:50'`, the format is `%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S`

For the latter case, the `T` is automatically added between date and time, replacing the space, when the string is converted to "date & time" type field (like, `to_datetime()` function). I agree it is a misleading description, because `PointsToPaths` does not accept `date` or `datetime` types.

I think the plugin author tried to emphasize that it can accept `'2015-01-25T13:45:50'` so that most of us (who store the datetime data in "date & time" type field) can easily use it just by `to_string()` conversion.

By the way, `Points to path` geoalgorithm is also available in the `Processing Toolbox | QGIS geoalgorithms | Vector creation tools`.

Comment: Thanks for sticking with me! I did an experiment: If the input format is 2015-05-31T23:58:59 and in the tool I use %Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S, an error is returned. If I use %Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S, also an error.  Thus it would appear that I cannot have a T in the input data.  If I replace the T in the data to a blank, 2015-05-31 23:58:59, and in the tool I use %Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S, an error is returned.  However, if I use %Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S, success!  In summary, my only solution is to have a blank in the data and a blank in the format.  This is at odds with my op, so now I am very confused....

Comment: Hi @StuSmith thanks for your feedback. Great to hear that you found a successful combination.
At this end I made a few tests on `Points to path` tool in `Processing Toolbox` (so this isn't an apples-to-apples comparison to the Plugin, sorry).
With QGIS2.14LTR, I could NOT make any paths regardless the combinations (Nothing worked... with T or space).
But QGIS 2.18.6 produced paths for both combinations in my answer. This outcome is strange, but it also gives me a hope that you may be able to give a try to `Points to path` tool as you are using QGIS 2.18.6. (if you can find a time to try).